# Access Android XML Layouts in Flutter

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter, ironsource

I am developing a mobile app using Flutter and I chose **IronSource** as my ad network. I tried integrating that by following their documentation. The **interstitial ad** is working just fine. However, my issue is when adding a **banner ad**. The documentation requires me to have XML layouts to design the banner and then load the ad into it. [this](https://developers.ironsrc.com/ironsource-mobile/android/banner-integration-android/#step-1) is the link for that documentation.

For the interstitial ad, I have written the code in the native java language and used platform channels from flutter to show it.

But I don't understand how to implement the banner ad with/without XML layout which i can use in flutter. Any advise or help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to add the ad around your FlutterView.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you provide me a sample example on how to do that?